# Dynamic Time Warping algorithm

Tags: java, dynamic, time, comparison, signals

I have some problems in my graduated project about dynamic time warping algorithm. i use dynamic time warping to compare different signals. I did this comparison. However,the result is very poor because of differences between two signals size or time. Is it possible to compare different size files? If it is possible, what is your advice? Thank you for helping.

Comment: please provide more information such as the two sequences of which you calculate the DTW distance and possibly the code you used to do so. Only then you can except substanial help by fellow users. In which way is the result poor?

Comment: This library, with its documentation, could help you a lot: https://github.com/talcs/simpledtw

Answer (score 0):

yes it is , you can compare tow time series (signals) that have different length with DTW algorithm but be sure you are using the right library , i recommend [dtaidistance](https://pypi.org/project/dtaidistance/)  library for python